# How to adjust size of bootable live USB and actually make it work?

Tags: boot, usb, live-usb, usb-creator

Firstly, I'd like to say that I read the entire article here, and tried method 0, which seemed like the easiest and most recommended.

What I want to do is create a USB version of Ubuntu that I can put into various computers and boot from - with persistent storage.  Meaning that I can save my settings and documents and move from computer to computer.

[This link](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LiveUsbPendrivePersistent#Method_0:_Automatically_create_Live_USB_system) says to use `gksudo usb-creator-gtk` which should be a vary simple process.  However, at one point it says to

> It says to "set the degree of persistence (the slider)

But when I run the program, I do not see any setting for persistence at all.  Instead it just writes something to disk (with no options).

Inserting the drive into my computer afterwards, I can indeed boot into Ubuntu, however, there is no persistent storage.  When I boot off the drive I get the typical "would you like to install Ubuntu or give Ubuntu a try?" and when I reboot it asks me to remove the drive.

Comment: If you have access to a Windows machine, there's a program called [Rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie/) that works the best IMO, and allows you to create persistence.  I know this is an Ubuntu site, but I've never found another program that works as good or better than Rufus.  Unetbootin sometimes doesn't even boot properly.

Comment: 16.04 removed the persistence capability -- Did you try an older system like 14.04?